# React to the last message of a specific channel discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I've been trying to make a bot to react to the last message of a specific channel. So, if I do run this command from a channel X (something like ;remreact 'emote'), then it'll react with the 'emote' to the latest message in channel Y. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are searching for:

```
    let emoji = msg[2];
    let chn = msg[1];
    message.channel.send(emoji);
    client.channels.cache.get(chn).send(emoji);
```

Comment: That does work for sending a message. I'm trying to get it to react, just as it does with message.react(emote)